# In Power SHell set alias cp to cp -v

Tags: shell, powershell, alias, cp

I have cp for power shell. But I want to use cp in verbose mode without writing -v. So cp should be aliased to "cp -v" command. How to alias cp to "cp -v" in power shell?

Comment: [What are you really trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171857)

Comment: I have cp for power shell. But I want to use cp in verbose mode without writing -v. So cp should be aliased to "cp -v" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias` command will not create parameters.  You'll have to delete the existing alias for `cp` and use a function:

```
Remove-Item alias:cp
Function cp { Copy-Item -v @args }
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468145/equivalent-to-bash-alias-in-powershell).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new alias for calling cp with the `Verbose` flag:

```
function Copy-ItemWithVerbose
{
    Copy-Item -Verbose @args 
}
Set-Alias -Name cpv -Value Copy-ItemWithVerbose
```

Answer (score 0):

in PS3 you can use this:

```
PS III> $PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Copy-item:verbose","$true")
PS III> cp
```